# All react-run commands don't work. | UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot. Previously his commands were working fine but now I'm getting an error. All react-run commands no longer work.

Error:

```
(node:1335) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
```

(node:1335) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

A sample code working with React:

````
 
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
 
  let pages = [
              "**Gold Üye Nedir?** \n **Gold Üye** Sistemi, sadece Gold Üye olanların kullanabileceği komutları içerir. Gold Üyeler, botun daha eğlenceli ve işlevsel komutlarını kullanmaya hak kazanır.\n\n**Gold Üye Nasıl Olunur?**\n Gold Üyelikler şuan için sadece [destek sunucusunda](https://discord.gg/3krnKD27Mf) çeşitli etkinlikler, çekilişler veya ücretli olarak verilmektedir.\n **Gold Komutlar için lütfen bir sonraki sayfaya geçiniz.**",
              "**Gold Komutlar** \n\n ``!drake`` Drake meme kullanırsınız.\n ``!snake`` Yılan oyunu oynarsınız.\n ``!çeviri (Ülke Kısaltması) (Çevirilecek Metin)`` Belirtilen metni, belirtilen dile çevirir. (örn. !trans en Merhaba)."
              ];
  let page = 1;
 
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('a900ff')
    .setThumbnail('')
    .setFooter(`Sayfalar arası dolaşmak için aşağıdaki okları kullan. Sayfa ${page} / ${pages.length}`)
    .setDescription(pages[page-1])
  message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {
 
  msg.react('⬅')
  .then(r => {
    msg.react('➡')
 
      //Filter
      const backwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⬅' && user.id === message.author.id;
      const forwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '➡' && user.id === message.author.id;
 
      const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector(backwardsFilter, { time: 100000 });
      const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector(forwardsFilter, { time: 100000 });
 
      forwards.on('collect', r => {
        if(page === pages.length) return;
        page++;
        embed.setDescription(pages[page-1]);
        embed.setColor('a900ff')
        embed.setFooter(`Sayfalar arası dolaşmak için aşağıdaki okları kullan. Sayfa ${page} / ${pages.length}`)
        msg.edit(embed)
      })
      backwards.on('collect', r => {
        if(page === 1) return;
        page--;
        embed.setColor('RANDOM')
        embed.setDescription(pages[page-1]);
        embed.setFooter(`Sayfalar arası dolaşmak için aşağıdaki okları kullan. Sayfa ${page} / ${pages.length}`)
        msg.edit(embed)
      })
 
    })
  })
};
 
 
exports.conf = {
enabled: true,
guildOnly: true,
aliases: ["goldbilgi", "goldne", "goldyardım", "yardimgold", "yardımgold", "gold-yardım", "yardım-gold", "yardim-gold"],
permLevel: 0
};
 
exports.help = {
name: 'gold',
description: 'Yardım Listesini Gösterir',
cooldown: 5,
usage: 'yardım'
};```
````

Comment: see this `msg.react('⬅').then(.......)`? add a `.catch(...........)` after it

Comment: how can I do it? idk...

Comment: add a `.catch(...........)` like I said